# Youtube video embed withenforce subtitles

Tags: youtube, captions

I use the following string on my website to enforce a subtitle language for a youtube video:

hl=en&cc_lang_pref=en&cc_load_policy=1

Since a short? time it stopped working, I think youtube changed something. Anyone an idea how to solve this problem? Or does anyone know how to enforce a subtitle on a youtube movie? Can't find anything on the youtube website.

Thanks.

Pieter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error by youtube. After two weeks the problem was solved.